# can syntax of while loop be a variable with no value assigned to it in the beginning?

Tags: c, while-loop

```
int fact,num[55];
k=0;
while(fact)
{
 num[k++] = fact%1000;
 fact/=1000;
}
```

1. What does this code mean?
2. If `fact` is initialized to `1` then how does the above code run? i.e `int fact=1;`

Comment: while(1) runs forever.....

Comment: @Madan; Accidentally I rejected your edit. My bad. Sorry for that.

Comment: @haccks no problem. make sure question looks proper at the end of the day. doesn't matter who edited it.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What does the following code mean?

This means your code invokes *undefined behavior* (as you are accessing the uninitialized variable `fact`) .

> If fact is initialized to 1 then how does the above code run? i.e int fact=1;

Loop will iterate only once. `1/1000 = 0` and hence `fact` will become `false` after first iteration.

Comment: The first part is correct. The second part (looking at the current version of the question) is not, since `fact` is modified inside the loop and will be set to `0` on the first iteration.

Comment: @KeithThompson; Oops! Now its time to take a break.